# Prevent LaTex from word wrapping subsequent lines

Tags: hyphenation

I am writing (partially) in german. German words tend to be quite long and my page is rather slim (I'm using the classicthesis template). So words get wrapped quite often which results in a lot of subsequent lines ending with dashes. Typographically, this is not very nice:

[image: Furious Line breaking]

Is there a way to prevent that? I know that programs, such as Indesign have such a feature. Is there something similar for LaTeX?!

Comment: Might you be able to rewrite the text to either use shorter words or rearrange the phrases so that the long words don't occur near line ends? Either approach will reduce the need for hyphenation. IMNSHO, the main problem with the hyphenations in your paragraph is not so much their frequency but the choices of two of the hyphenation breakpoints: Things would be quite unobjectionable if the words were broken after "Quanten" and "Interferenz".

Comment: You could also try increasing the [\pretolerance](http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/pretolerance).

Comment: I tried adjusting the pretolerance. For 0-9999 this doesn't change anything (not in that page at least, didn't check the whole document). For 10000 it looks even uglier:
    [link](https://i.imgur.com/g3NnW4t.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [microtype](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package tries to make a better justification and other small typographic improvements.

The [impnattypo](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/impnattypo) package has the option `hyphenation`:

> the suggested implementation strongly discourages hyphenation
>   at the end of pages, as well as hyphenation on two consecutive lines.

Comment: Tried the impnattypo package with option hyphenation. Now, only three consecutive lines are hyphenated, but one is longer than the others: [link](https://i.imgur.com/Xueepyl.png)

Comment: I have included the microtype package already. Tried protrusion=true,expansion options, but to no avail.

Comment: Then you have to change your text.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm going to do then. Thanks a lot for your suggestions!